# Open Solution from Source Control VSTS - wrong path

Tags: azure-devops

I recently converted my TFS Server to VSTS for source control.  I used the opshub migration tool and thought that everything was working fine.  However, today I went to open a project I have not worked with for a while and find that the local path when I am looking at the source control explorer is a drive and location that has never existed and I have to assume came from the migration. [image: Local Path on Source Control]

When I try to open the file I get an error that it can't find the part of the path...which makes sense since it doesn't exist.

[image]
What do I need to do in order to change that to a location that does exist so I can work on that project?

Comment: Update your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot, the sources are not downloaded for your current workspace.

Just try to right-click on the project node (`Operations` in your case) in the left panel, then select `Get Latest Version` to download them.

If that still not work, then you can try to create a new workspace or remap the current workspace.

[image]